# Error changing build sdk in adroid studio

Tags: java, android, sdk, dependencies, targetsdkversion

When I change both the targetsSdkVersion and the compileSdkVersion to 26, i get an error. I have tried chnaging it through the Project structure settings, and manually, but it keeps giving me the following error:

> AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>   [image: error dialogCirnerRadius not found]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.agriplanner3"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: it might not be this but, just in case, go to the sources and check that your resource that has the `dialogCornerRadius` is in the right directory. I had a similar error long time ago and it was due to this

Answer (score 0):

```
change sdk version like below and sync project

compileSdkVersion 29
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 29
```